# 404 when post submitted; found when directly called

Tags: forms, http, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion enabled form (for validation) submitting to a separate page. When this form is submitted it is showing me a 404 on the action page, yet when I directly load the action url into the address bar it shows up (errors appear, but that's ok). This is by far one of the most odd issues I have encountered.

Form page: http://www.jefferson.edu/population_health/_archive/contact_me.cfm

Action page: http://www.jefferson.edu/population_health/_archive/contact_action.cfm

Even if I try passing the form variables via URL it gives me a 404.

Comment: Have you ever had issues with POST data on that web service before? Perhaps they don't allow the POST method and don't return correct error responses?

Comment: Try renaming mailaction.cfm to something else and move it to a different directory and see what happens.  It could be something with IIS settings aliasing that directory when a POST happens.

Comment: @animuson, I have not.  It's a very basic, non-customized web server.

Comment: @Benjamin, I did rename it, and it's still not working.  Now I'm really baffled, as your idea was most sound!

Comment: Your form page won't work with any URL variables (GET) appended to it either.  Just curious, can you submit a form on any page on the site?  Is it a .cfm page?  What about trying an .html page?  (Trying to narrow it down between apache and cf.)

Comment: @Sharondio, is that a question?

Comment: I hit "add Comment" before finishing.  Edited comment above.

Comment: When I append URL variables it gives me a 404.

Comment: Is this site running on Apache or IIS?  I ask because I'm getting different response headers depending on whether I hit the page with or without appended variables.  My gut is that you've got some rogue mapping somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My gut is that there is another service on that machine that is trying to take over the request whenever you submit data and binding it to another webserver...which, of course, it can't find the right page based on it's own webroot.

If you click http://www.jefferson.edu/population_health/_archive/contact_me.cfm, it loads fine and returns 200 header with IIS as the server, but if you click http://www.jefferson.edu/population_health/_archive/contact_me2.cfm it throws a 404, as expected, but it's properly handled with a custom 404 and the header response is still IIS.  But if you click http://www.jefferson.edu/population_health/_archive/contact_me.cfm?foo=bar, it returns an ApacheSling default 404 and header information saying the server is "Day-Servlet-Engine/4.1.12".

Comment: Wow, good job.  We have Adobe CQ5 running on the same box, and Apache Sling should be ignoring url/form variables being passed, but of course it isn't. *sigh*  So, I'm moving these files completely out of the population_health/ folder and somewhere else.

Comment: So much easier to debug these things when you can hit the OPs actual server.  Glad to help!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your page is posting to the page contact_action.cfm ... in your question you indicate that the proper page should be "mailaction.cfm".

If the action page is actually mailaction.cfm then you simply need to change the action attribute of your cfform.

Comment: Also remember that on some configurations of web server it could be case sensitive.

Comment: I changed the mail action source to point to contact_action.cfm, and am getting the same 404.